# GWT CellTable : Add / Delete a row in a CellTable

Tags: gwt, celltable

Is the GWT CellTable designed to only display records and update the existing ones.

Can one add and delete a record from a CellTable, any pointers to a stable solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can add and remove data rows by manipulating the model object backing the CellTable display.

```
ListDataProvider<OrderLineWeek> model = new ListDataProvider<OrderLineWeek>();
model.addDataDisplay(myCellTableInstance);
```

You can then access the list through `model.getList()`, but you must call `model.refresh()`, or `table.setRowCount(model.getList().size())` if you have added or deleted any rows.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, a really nice feature would be to allow the user interaction to  proceed beyond the last row and that would trigger an add 'event'. Of course, one could either create an empty row for this purpose, or hook into key events to manipulate the backing data provider.

Answer (score 4):

```
ListDataProvider.getList().remove(index);
DataGrid.redraw(); // to refresh
```

to add, create object then assign data to this object,

```
ListDataProvider.getList.Add(object);

DataGrid.redraw();
```